# Based on what should i choose an amplifier to implement a Howland current pump with?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, amplifier, feedback, source

I selected some amplifiers based on their input and output voltage since the howlands Gain is Vin/R also on how much current the amplifier can supply. i selected ones that are 100mA and up, what other considerations should i keep in mind ?? also if you have a recommendation that would be great.

Comment: Do you really need a Howland source? If you don't need a bipolar source they're often not the best solution.

Comment: We can't give recommendations if we don't know what you need. Give more details about your application. Why are you specifically using a Howland current source, as opposed to a simple current mirror or Widlar current source?

Comment: I need my source to be bipolar as it's used to drive a coil to produce a magnetic field and i need 40mA at the least but the more the better.

Comment: @Sphero what is a better solution then ??

Comment: See below......

Answer (score 2):

You can use this circuit, which is better than a Howland source unless you really need one side of the coil grounded.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFa9S1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You may wish to put some diodes on the output of the op-amp to either supply rail, and put hefty enough bypass capacitors that the stored energy in the inductance can't over-voltage the amplifier.

40mA is pretty easy, you could also just use a regular op-amp and a couple of emitter followers (PNP/NPN) on the output if you are not concerned about crossover distortion. If you are, then you need to bias the transistors somewhat 'on', and there are many schematics available of op-amp boosters.